# Filtering on nested array of objects to return the entire matching object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, filtering, javascript-objects

My array of nested objects looks like this along with the array to match it with

```
let findThis = ["Water"];
    let arrayOfElements = 
    [
            {
               "code": "a",
               "templates": [
                 {
                   "templateCode": "Water",
                   "title": "Earth"
                 },
                 {
                   "templateCode": "Milk",
                   "title": "Sky"
                 }
                 
                ]
            },
            {
               "code": "b",
               "templates": []
            },
            {
               "code": "c",
               "templates": [
                 {
                   "templateCode": "Water",
                   "title": "Earth"
                 },
                 {
                   "templateCode": "Tree",
                   "title": "Moon"
                 }
            },
            {
               "code": "d",
               "templates": [
                 {
                   "templateCode": "Tooth",
                   "title": "Tiger"
                 }
            }
    ]
```

I want to extract those objects whose `templateCode` is `Water`. So my final returned array should look like this.

```
let result = 
[
        {
           "code": "a",
           "templates": [
             {
               "templateCode": "Water",
               "title": "Earth"
             },
             {
               "templateCode": "Milk",
               "title": "Sky"
             }
             
            ]
        },
        {
           "code": "c",
           "templates": [
             {
               "templateCode": "Water",
               "title": "Earth"
             },
             {
               "templateCode": "Tree",
               "title": "Moon"
             }
        }
]
```

I tried:

```
arrayOfElements.filter(x => x.templates.filter(y => findThis.includes(y.templateCode)));
```

But it is returning the entire array itself and is not working.

Comment: The first inner function needs to return truthy or falsy for `.filter` to work.  It's currently returning the result of another filter, which is guaranteed to be truthy.

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to get it. I am trying to iterate over the template array of each object.

Comment: inside use `some` instead of filter which will return true if there is at least one element that satisfies `findThis.includes(y.templateCode)`

Comment: Yes, you are, but you are using filter to do so, which returns empty array [] if nothing matched, and populated array [match, match] if it found matches.  That is no good to return to arrayOfElements.filter as both arrays are considered truthy.  Consider [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `filter` the `arrayOfElements` with the condition of any `templateCode` existing inside the `findThis` array.

```js
let findThis = ["Water"];
    let arrayOfElements = 
    [
            {
               "code": "a",
               "templates": [
                 {
                   "templateCode": "Water",
                   "title": "Earth"
                 },
                 {
                   "templateCode": "Milk",
                   "title": "Sky"
                 }
                 
                ]
            },
            {
               "code": "b",
               "templates": []
            },
            {
               "code": "c",
               "templates": [
                 {
                   "templateCode": "Water",
                   "title": "Earth"
                 },
                 {
                   "templateCode": "Tree",
                   "title": "Moon"
                 }
                 ]
            },
            {
               "code": "d",
               "templates": [
                 {
                   "templateCode": "Tooth",
                   "title": "Tiger"
                 }
                 ]
            }
    ]
    
const result = arrayOfElements.filter(item => item.templates.some(t => findThis.includes(t.templateCode)))

console.log(result)
```